# How to make a distribution curve given id and corresponding value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset of 1.6 million ids and their corresponding values.

The mean of the values is 2.02 and the standard deviation is 4.63. The maximum value is 531 and the minimum value is -3.5.

I want to make a distribution curve using matplotlib in which the X-axis corresponds to the value and Y-axis corresponds to the probability.

However, the problem is that there are very few ids having exactly the same value.

The distribution curve would help me in getting the probability of an id having value between a given range.

The problem is that there are very few ids having exactly the same value. Hence I can't simply count the number of ids corresponding to every value and then plot the graph.

Comment: Do you want to make an [histogram](https://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html)?

Comment: @berna1111 Distribution curve would be better. But histogram could also help

Comment: The example in the link (blue text) has both, does it work for you?